# Pure Javascript alternative to JQuery's .on() function

Tags: javascript

I have written a small pure javascript library that replaces JQuery (keeping syntax the same as JQuery, but the code javascript).  I'm struggling to get the .on function to work correctly when I pass an event object to it, as the event is not passed back (in case I want to prevent bubbling up).

The first set of code is my library:

```
(function () {

var Q = function (params) {
    return new Library(params);
};

var Library = function (params) {

    if (typeof params === 'string') {
        var selector = document.querySelectorAll(params),
            counter;

        this.length = selector.length;

        // Add selector to object for method chaining
        for (counter = 0; counter < this.length; counter++) {
            this[counter] = selector[counter];
        }
    } else {
        this.length = 1;

        this[0] = params;
    }

    // Return as object
    return this;        
};
 
Q.fn = Library.prototype = {

    /*
        Name            addClass()
        Description     Adds a class to the objects
        Input           className TEXT
        Language        Javascript
    */

    addClass: function (classNames) {
        var arr = classNames.split(' '),
            total = arr.length,
            counter,
            count;

        for (counter = 0; counter < this.length; counter++) {

            for (count = 0; count < total; count++) {

                if (!this[counter].classList.contains(arr[count])) {
                    this[counter].classList.add(arr[count]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Return this to allow chained methods
        return this;
    },

     on: function (events) {
        var arr = events.split(' '),
            total = arr.length,
            counter,
            count;

        if (arguments.length === 2) {
            // .on('change', function(e) { ... });

            for (counter = 0; counter < this.length; counter++) {

                for (count = 0; count < total; count++) {
                    this[counter].addEventListener(arr[count], arguments[1], false);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // .on('change', 'input', function(e) { ... });

            var doc = document,
                selector = arguments[1],
                func = arguments[2],
                counter;

            for (counter = 0; counter < this.length; counter++) {

                var obj = this[counter];

                if (isset(obj)) {

                    for (count = 0; count < total; count++) {
                        doc.addEventListener(arr[count], function() {

                            if (arguments[0].target.matches(obj.tagName + ' ' + selector)) {
                                func.call(arguments[0].target, arguments[0]);
                            }

                        }, false);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Return this to allow chained methods
        return this;
    },

};   

// Assign our Q object to global window object.
if (!window.Q) {
    window.Q = Q;
}
})();
```

When I use the following in my code, all works well, but the event returned doesn't contain the updated properties:

```
 Q(obj).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I'll gladly share more info, and I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe I am nitpicking but jQuery **is** written in javascript.

Comment: jQuery **is** Javascript.  You're literally asking to rewrite jQuery.

Comment: You can check how jquery implement `on` function.

Comment: [This is a good blog post](http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery), and even includes a very basic `on` handler, after which it says _"Of course this is a very primitive implementation, lacking many features, but we are not going to reinvent jQuery."_

Comment: AtheistP3ace, you are allowed to nitpick.  :-)  But yes, we are switching from JQuery to no libraries / frameworks. Since we used JQuery, it is easiest to write something with the same syntax, but lighter.

Comment: James Thorpe - I had a look at your recommended article, I have to agree it is good! I tried the .on function in my code, trying to adapt it, but couldn't get it to work. But a great first try, thank you (I've saved that article for further reading)

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the code correct, it is because when you call the callback

```
func.call(arguments[0].target, arguments[0]);
```

You do not pass the event

Comment: epascarello, I agree with you, and that is my issue, how do I do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `func.apply(arguments[0].target, arguments);`